# Can you import JavaScript (or other non CSS) files using the @import CSS function?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-import

I know you can't do this on Chrome as I tried it and it failed. When I run the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Test</p>
    <style>
        @import "script.js";
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

with a 'script.js' file in the same folder I get the following error in the chrome console:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iftKy.png)

My questions are:

1. Is this the same for all browsers?
2. Is there a workaround which allows you to import and run non .css files using the @import function?

Comment: no! absolutely no! without question, no! what's wrong with a script tag, or an javascript `import` - sounds like you're [STILL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64370131/can-javascript-still-be-run-from-a-url-in-2020) trying to find an *exploit*

Comment: That is correct, As I said in my other question, I am trying to secure my site against XSS attacks. The issue is, as I need to enable a third-party service on my site, I need to enable 'unsafe-inline' in my style-src CSP directive. I am just trying to make sure any of these exploits I've seen online (relating to CSS exploits) won't work on my site.

Comment: Well, I guess someone with netscape navigator or internet explorer x (where x is a single digit) or ncsa mosaic may have a problem - or chrome ... just kidding, chrome just stops working every second release

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That is sort of what I assumed but I wanted to clarify with someone a bit more knowledgeable than myself. So I know I understood correctly, you are saying that most modern browsers won't enable this functionality?

Comment: if, instead of "enable this functionality" you mean "allow such security risk", then, yes, no modern browser would "enable this functionality"

Comment: can I be perfectly frank with you, and I really mean no offence - your two questions could be presented a bit better - you kind of look like a "script kiddie" looking for a way to "exploit" - rather than an IT professional ensuring the safety of a product

Comment: Thats a perfectly fine response, I can see from the responses I've received on my questions that I could have definitely worded my questions better. Its a new area for me that I'm not hugely knowledgeable on, so thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can you import JavaScript (or other non CSS) files using the @import CSS function?

The short answer is... no.

`@import` is built to import stylesheets. A common misconception is that you can import non-CSS files by doing the following:

```
@import url("chrome://communicator/skin/");
```

However, the only reason the line ending is dropped is because the URL for a native browser package need not actually specify a file; it can just specify the package name and part, and the appropriate file is chosen automatically (e.g. chrome://communicator/skin/). [See here for details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/XUL/Tutorial/The_Chrome_URL).

For more information, see the MDN docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import) about `@import`.